# What are the colours for in Java Mission Control's MBean Browser?

Tags: java, jmx, java-mission-control

I cannot seem to find any details on what these colours are supposed to indicate or be related to.

[image: Screenshot of JMC MBean Browser]

As far as I can tell they don't appear to correlate to anything, and multiple instances of the same MBean interface have different colours assigned to the same attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Alexandre says, they are used in the charts.
If you add an attribute to a chart, you can right-click in the chart legend and choose to change the color for that attribute, this will also update the color on the MBean Browser page.
If no specific color is set, we will just use hash value of the attribute object to create a color, so that's why the colors appear very random.

Comment: Seem like odd design decisions. Why not assign visually distinct colours when adding to charts. You can't even see the Attributes tab and the charts at the same time can you?

Comment: Can't really argue with you there, but that's how it works :)  The idea is probably to always have the same color for the same attribute, even if it's included in more than one chart.

Answer (score 2):

Those colors will be used if you add the attributes to a charts (right click on an attribute and click "visualize").